# How to transform RDFS to RDFS?

Tags: .net, xslt, rdf, rdfs

I have two RDF schemas and I need to convert one to another.
Is there any transformation language analogue to XSLT just for RDFS?
I'm looking for a possible implementation in .NET, but other platforms are welcomed as well.

Comment: Can you clarify - if you already have both schemas, why do you need to convert one to the other? Do you mean that you have RDF data that follows one RDFS schema that you want to convert to follow another RDFS schema??

Comment: I need to define mapping from one RDFS schema to another RDFS schema.

Answer (score 3):

I would load the RDF into a triple store with SPARQL 1.1 support, and then use SPARQL CONSTRUCT queries to generate RDF that matches the target RDF schema.

Probably it takes more than one CONSTRUCT query if the structure of your data is on the complex side.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of how you implement the transformation I'd go with cygri's suggestion.  Though it may be possible to do it entirely at the API level depending on the complexity of your transformation.

Try out [dotNetRDF](http://www.dotnetrdf.org) if you want a .Net API for doing this (*disclaimer - I develop this*).  It has a SPARQL 1.1 engine built in and a fairly comprehensive API for manipulating RDF directly

AFAIK there is no general analogue to XSLT for RDF, there have been a few attempts at designing such a thing but I don't know of any that have actually been particularly popular or widely used.